Random number delay
I was hoping someone could tell me to add a delay to a random number generator in Simulink. I am a college student and this is my first semester using this software, so I am not aware of all the functions. I am trying to simulate an automated power management system, which works kinda like a CVT, where the engine/transmission will change in response to a dynamic work load. What I have right now is a random number that changes every 10 seconds, and I am using that number as a multiplier to a base force. What I have an issue with however, is I want the number to slowly change from n1 to n2 over the 10 seconds instead of instantaneously changing at 10 second intervals. I tried using variations of delays such as 1/s-x, I also tried moving average with a window set to 10 and overlap 1, and I tried using a median filter. I couldn't get the result I wanted, but it is also worth noting that maybe I was using the right block, just didn't have it set up right. Please help if you're able to!


